# two functions in samba

Tags: linux, unix, samba

I want to setup a samba for file sharing in my intranet, but I want to know if there is any way to prohibit some kind of files (e.g *.exe) uploaded to the share folder? And I want to know if there is any way to force the user to change the password for the first time login?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Better suited for http://serverfault.com/ Good luck.

Comment: @shellter: Or SuperUser.com. I flagged it for SU.

Comment: yes, that works too. Good luck to all.

Comment: Try to limit your questions to only one per post.

Answer (score 0):

The [`veto files`](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html#VETOFILES) configuration option might be what you are looking for to prevent certain files from being allowed.

Use it like this in the smb.conf:
`veto files = /*.extension1/*.extension2/`